# How to animate div automatically with browser scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to animate class colm1,colm2,colm3 when browser scroll to project div . this code work when i click the button .but i want to this animate with scrolling

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $(".project").hide();


      $(".navbar #project").click(function() {  

         $(".colm1").slideDown(3000);
$(".colm2").slideDown(4000);
$(".colm3").slideDown(5000);
  });
 });
```

Help me 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you need, but maybe this'll help)

```
                $(document).scroll(function () {
                    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 10) {
                        $(".colm1").slideDown(3000);
                        $(".colm2").slideDown(4000);
                        $(".colm3").slideDown(5000);
                    }
                });
```